# autologin on webpage?

Tags: browser, login, lan

I need to type in my username and pass to connect to internet through a captive portal provided by my ISP is there a automatic way(any software/script) to type in info(in username and pass fields) and login  without me typing and pressing the login button every time on my browser(chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

Is it good enough to save the login info in Chrome and "only" have to press the login button? If so, tehre is probably built-in functionality in Chrome for that.

If that's not good enough, you could most likely figure out what is sent to your ISP when you click the button, and then "fake" (that is, duplicate) the same content on a local web page. Set the local web page to your start page (and make sure that it is allowed to run scripts) and you could automate this.

To figure out what is sent, you could look for some way to monitor network traffic between Chrome and teh intarwebz. In Firefox, I'd use Firebug (a free add-on) to analyze the traffic, and code the local script from that. Once you're done with the script, you can open it in Chrome and it should work there too.

Comment: i installed firebug on mozilla but how to use it to find what is sent?

Comment: Go to the Net panel and enable it (using the little arrow next to the title). You'll get a row for each request, and if you expand the request node you'll find lots of information. You'll also see the entire server response, as well as response status code etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend: Lastpass.com - it's an add-on for a lot of browsers. In Firefox, there is an option to login automatically, but in some pages, like live.com , don't do that. I think I saw that on Lastpass in my (buggy) Chrome installation

Comment: P.S. LastPass was "potentially" breached. http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9216455/LastPass_alerts_users_about_potential_master_password_breach

Comment: super recent news!!! thanks! well, password online storage will have allways potential risks because hackers are "password-hungry"... so now I'll change all my passwords :) - it's a secure way and have to be done often... I'll continue to use LastPass. I think there are another ways to do what blackjack wants, but it is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux I've a solution for you:

In the folder /etc/if-up.d you can put a script, that will be automatically run every time a connection is established, to do the autologin for you.
I've written a little guide (in italian, sorry, but you can translate it using google translate) with an example of script.

You can find all this material on http://minus.com/mH37X6XVE